# How to use SQL Server table hints while using LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net, transactions

What is the way to use Sql Server's table hints like "NOLOCK" while using LINQ?

For example I can write "SELECT * from employee(NOLOCK)" in SQL.

How can we write the same using LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can apply NOLOCK: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx

(Quote for posterity, all rights reserved by mr scott):

```
ProductsNewViewData viewData = new ProductsNewViewData();
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions { 
        IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
    }))
{
   viewData.Suppliers = northwind.Suppliers.ToList();
   viewData.Categories = northwind.Categories.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I STRONGLY recommend reading about SQL Server transaction isolation modes before using ReadUncommitted.
Here's a very good read

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidlean/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas)

In many cases level `ReadSnapshot` should suffice. Also you if You really need it You can set default transaction isolation level for Your database by using

```
Set Transaction Isolation Level --levelHere
```

Other good ideas include packaging Your context in a wrapper that encapsulates each call using demanded isolation level. (maybe You need nolock 95% of the time and serializable 5% of the time). It can be done using using extension methods, or normal methods by code like:

```
viewData.Categories = northwind.Categories.AsReadCommited().ToList();
```

Which takes your IQueryable and does the trick mentioned by Rob.

Hope it helps
Luke