# How to use table hints in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

How can I use table hints in LINQ to SQL when calling submit changes method?

```
dataContext.table2.something = dataContext.table1.something;
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I want to generate something like this SQL code:

```
declare @var int;
begin transaction
select @var = something from table1 with (HoldLock);
update table2 set something = @var;
update table1 set something = @var + 1;
commit transaction;
```

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104323/how-to-use-sql-server-table-hints-while-using-linq

Comment: What hints do you exactly need to add? Depending on it there can be different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always heard that cant be done. Linq's goal (or at least one of them) is take or mind out of SQL so you dont have to worry with things like this. I suggest that you add your code with the table hint to a SQL procedure and use Linq to call it.

Comment: unfortunately for some reasons i can't use stored procedure

Comment: how about views, table functions? or you cant create any objects on the DB

Comment: i can create views only but how can this help??

Comment: I would if it were only a select statement you needed, but I see you need an update too

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

Actually, it is possible by doing serious nasty hacking using reflection. You can compile a query, and then fiddle with the generated SQL string in some internal object. This is the least desirable way to do this.

I recommend you stay with raw SQL for this one.